# Yii CGridView Not Updating With JS Call

Tags: php, ajax, yii, cgridview

What I'm trying to accomplish with the following code is when the 'roleSelector' dropdown is changed, it fires a ajax request to the 'admin/permissions/assign' url which in turn, sets a state for the role selected.  I need it as a state so I can use it in the CLinkColumn column within the CGridView.  However, when the success javascript fires and the grid view reloads the content of the cgridview does not update, while the summary does (it shows the number of results that should be in the grid view).

I'm not sure why either but this seems to be the only CGridView that I've had to use the 'ajaxUrl' property in order for the $.fn.yiiGridView.update() call to work.  If I omit the url property it returns an error stating it could not find the url which I don't recall having to set in the past.

The Action:

```
class AssignAction extends CAction {

    // Used in the url to determine if we are assigning or revoking permissions
    const FLAG_APPLY = 'apply';
    const FLAG_REVOKE = 'revoke';

    // Identifier to the user saved state of the role selected
    const STATE_ROLE = 'roleSelected';

    public function run($name='', $action='') {

        // Get the role the user selected
        if (isset($_POST['roleSelector'])) {
            $roleSelected = $_POST['roleSelector'];
            Yii::app()->user->setState(self::STATE_ROLE, $roleSelected);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        // Get all of the roles from the system
        $roleSelected = Yii::app()->user->getState(self::STATE_ROLE);
        $roles = AuthItem::model()->byTypes(array(CAuthItem::TYPE_ROLE))->findAll();
        $authItemProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('AuthItem', array(
            'criteria' => array(
                'condition' => (!$roleSelected) ? '1=0' : '',
            ),
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 30,
            )
        ));

        $this->getController()->render('assign', array(
            'roles' => $roles,
            'roleSelected' => $roleSelected,
            'authItemProvider' => $authItemProvider,
        ));
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<div id="content-header">
    <h1 class="p-mt10">Assign Permissions</h1>
    <div class="p-fr p-pb10">
        <?php
            $roleList = CHtml::listData($roles, 'name', 'label');
            echo CHtml::dropDownList('roleSelector', $roleSelected, $roleList, $htmlOptions=array(
                'empty' => 'Select a Role',
                'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST',
                    'url' => $this->createUrl('/admin/permissions/assign'),
                    'data' => array('roleSelector' => 'js: $(this).val()'),
                    'success' => 'js: function() { $.fn.yiiGridView.update("GridView-AuthItem") }',
                ),
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content-body">
    <table>
        <?php
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'id' => 'GridView-AuthItem',
                'dataProvider' => $authItemProvider,
                'columns' => array(
                    'label:properCase',
                    'typeName:properCase',
                    'description',
                    'bizrule',
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CLinkColumn',
                        'label' => 'Assign',
                        'urlExpression' => 'array("/admin/permissions/assign",
                        "name" => $data->name,
                        "action" => (AuthItemChild::model()->byParentAndChild(Yii::app()->user->getState(AssignAction::STATE_ROLE), $data->name)->find()
                            ? AssignAction::FLAG_REVOKE : AssignAction::FLAG_APPLY),
                        )',
                        'htmlOptions' => array(
                            'style' => 'text-align: center',
                        ),
                        'linkHtmlOptions' => array(
                            'class' => 'button gray icon i_stm_edit',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot I left the table tags in there since it originally was a CListView.  Removing those tags seems to have fixed my problem.